# Can't solve this flow issue. Object.values(products)

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

```
const products = {
  'v1111': 'shoes',
  'v2222': 'bikes',
  'v3333': 'cars'
};
const productValues: Array<string> = Object.values(products);

    return productValues.map((name: string): React$Node => {
      const match = name === products[this.state.productChosen];
      return <ProductImage match={match} name={name} />;
    });
```

I've tried:

```
productValues: Array<string>
productValues: Array<React$Node>
productValues: Array<*>
```

can't get this typed correctly. Seems simple enough.. but the `Object.values` seems to be giving back a mixed type I can't correctly type.

> error: Error:(88, 27) Flow: function. This type is incompatible with
>   the expected param type of function type

Comment: seems like you are returning array of react components instead of array of strings.

Comment: I tried returning productValues: Array<React$Node>, didn't work. Same error. I think it needs some kind of tuple typing.

Comment: Import type as `import type {Node} from 'react';` and then use it like `productValues: Array<Node>` and `map((name: string): Node =>`

Comment: appreciate it, I tried - but didn't work.

Comment: I think I need to coerce the Object.values(products) into something else.